# Not overwriting variable?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, counter

I'm trying to count the elements inside an array, and the number has to be updated each time elements are added. I'm trying to do this by using the following function:

```
function counter() {
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        counter = i;
    }
    alert("counter has counted");
}
```

but it only works the first time! The second time the function is called it doesn't work anymore and the alert is not even showing up, so I guess the process gets interrupted in the for loop. Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: Why not just use ```elements.length```?

Comment: The line, `counter = i` overwrites the window property "counter", which was what your function was bound to. Thus, calling the function erases all memory of the function. It's pretty zen.

Comment: @Pointy: should be an answer...

Comment: Well Mr. Byers' answer was already there, if incomplete :-)

Comment: @Pointy: Then post a more complete answer!

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: your way makes much more sense than mine, so I changed the function to that, thank's!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use the same name (`counter`) for the variable that stores the count and for your function.

The line `counter = i;` overwrites the reference to your function. The next time you try to call `counter()` it won't work because `counter` is no longer a function.

Try this instead:

```
function update_counter() {
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        counter = i;
    }
    alert("counter has counted");
}
```

Comment: This. Since `counter = i;` doesn't use the `var` keyword, the value of `counter` is reassigned from a Function object to a Number primitive.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the line

```
counter = i
```

which is also the name of your function.

Consequently, the next time you call counter(), counter is actually set with an integer.